# JavaFX , fill accordion with fxml and Controller

Tags: java, controller, javafx-2, accordion, fxml

im new in java and javafx and i have a problem with an accordion.

basically,i want load 3 times the same fxml into an accordion with the new instances of the controller

```
    @FXML public void AddAccordion()
{   if(accordion.getPanes().size()<=14){
    this.main.titlepanelist.add( new TitledPane("Number: "+ (accordion.getPanes().size()), TitledPane));
        try {
                FXMLLoader loader= new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("Pane.fxml"));
                Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
                this.main.titlepaneliste.get(this.main.titlepaneliste.size()-1).setContent(root);

                PaneGuiController paneGuiController = loader.getController();
                paneGuiController.setMain(this.main,accordion.getPanes().size());

                accordion.getPanes().add(this.main.titlepaneliste.get(this.main.titlepanelist.size()-1));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }}
```

Here the Pane Controller:

```
public class CardioPaneController {
public Main main;
int nummer;
@FXML private TextField textfield;
@FXML private Button button;


public void setMain(Main main,int nummer) 
{
    this.main=main;
    his.nummer=nummer;
}

@FXML private void buttonclicked()
{
this.main.array[nummer].text=textfield.getText();
}
```

if i load it and print the content of this.main.array:

```
Array [0]=3
Array [1]=3
Array [2]=3
```

but it should print:

```
Array [0]=1
Array [1]=2
Array [2]=3
```

if i save the first content at last then it shows:

```
Array [0]=1
Array [1]=1
Array [2]=1
```

is there any Error i didn´t see?